# how to add a row before last row of the table using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to add a row before last row of the table and hidding the last row. The code is working fine including hidding last row of table. but not sure how to add row.

```
Sub StayOverRoom2()

Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim Name1 As String
Dim Name2 As String
Dim Check As Boolean
Dim Table As ListObject
Dim nRow As ListRow
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim strTableName As String

lRow1 = Sheets("DR01").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Sheets("DR02").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strTableName = "DailyReport2"

Set Table = Range(strTableName).ListObject

Sheets("DR02").Rows("1:150").EntireRow.Hidden = False

For i = 11 To lRow1
    Name1 = Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "C").Value
    Check = False

    For j = 11 To lRow2
        Name2 = Sheets("DR02").Cells(j, "C").Value

        If Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, 5) <= Date Or Name1 = Name2 Then
            Check = True
        End If
    Next j

    If Not Check Then
        Set nRow = Table.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
            Sheets("DR01").Range(Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "B"), Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "E")).Copy
            eRow = Sheets("DR02").Cells(Sheets("DR02").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            nRow.Range(1, 1).PasteSpecial
            nRow.Range(1, "E").Value = "S/O"
            nRow.Range(1, "F").Value = "-"
            nRow.Range(1, "G").Value = "-"
            nRow.Range(1, "H").Value = "-"
            nRow.Range(1, "I").Value = "-"
            nRow.Range(1, "J").Value = "-"
            nRow.Range(1, "K").Value = "-"
            Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M").Copy
            nRow.Range(1, "L").PasteSpecial

            If Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "R.D. - D" Or _
                Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "P.P.D. - D" Or _
                Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "C.R. - D" Then
                nRow.Range(1, "L") = "Daily"
            End If

            If Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "R.D. - W" Or _
                Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "P.P.D. - W" Or _
                Sheets("DR01").Cells(i, "M") = "C.R. - W" Then
                nRow.Range(1, "L") = "Weekly"
            End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i

lRow2 = Sheets("DR02").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("DR02").Rows(lRow2 & ":" & lRow2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Im trying to add a row before last row of the table and hidding the last row. The code is working fine including hidding last row of table. but not sure how to add row.

Answer (score 0):

Found by using the record macro tool

```
Thisworkbook.worksheets("name of your sheet").Row(lrow2).Insert shift:=xldown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove.
```